# Generic List of Structs in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, generic-list

I started working in Excel with VBA and would like to save some kind of List.

My approach is the following, but I fear that I am looking into the totally wrong direction.

```
Public Type MyType
  ID As Integer
  Name As String
  MyInt As Integer
End Type

Public ListVar As New Collection

Public Sub MySub
  Dim MyVar As MyType
  MyVar.ID = 1
  MyVar.Name = "name"
  MyVar.MyInt = 2000

  ListVar.Add MyVar, MyVar.ID
End Sub
```

When trying to execute, I get a compile error: "Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions."

The goal would be to have a C# like List to which I can add MyType-objects and find them in a way you can do it in C#: ListVar.find(p => p.ID == 3).
Also if doable, the list should be persistent in the file. This is not needed because I could simply write it into a worksheet when closing and vice versa when opening.

Is there maybe a different object class I can use that fits my needs better?

Comment: [see this](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s239/collections.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an array list? Within your Sub:

```
Dim arrayList As Object
Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

You can then use all the usual methods of the .NET type ArrayList such as `.Contains()` or `.Sort()` etc...

---

**Edit:** *(as OP is using Mac OS)*

You can create a class yourself, and use this in the collection. Start by creating a new class module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd>)

Use the following in this module:

```
Private sID     As Integer
Private sName   As String
Private sInt    As Integer

Public Property Let ID(value As Integer)
    sID = value
End Property

Public Property Get ID() As Integer
    ID = sID
End Property

Public Property Let Name(value As String)
    sName = value
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = sName
End Property

Public Property Let MyInt(value As Integer)
    sInt = value
End Property

Public Property Get MyInt() As Integer
    MyInt = sInt
End Property
```

**Important** - name the module "MyType", this is the name you want to use in your code.

Back to your original sub in a **normal** code module:

```
Public ListVar As New Collection

Public Sub MySub()

  Dim MyVar As New MyType
  MyVar.ID = 1
  MyVar.Name = "name"
  MyVar.MyInt = 2000

  ListVar.Add MyVar, CStr(MyVar.ID)

End Sub
```

Will work fine.

Comment: I started reading on the arrayList class. Might be what I was looking for. Unfortunately I get: "Runtime error '429': ActiveX component can't create object." on the Set arrayList = CreateObject(...) line

Comment: Are you using a mac?

Comment: yes, found out that this problem is not resolvable because it's stuck at version 5 -.-

Comment: Mac OS cannot create ActiveX objects, so you won't have any luck with this method. You can however create a class and use that - I'll update with an example.

Comment: Also note that the key has to be a string, so I've used `CStr()` - when calling the object back from the collection you will need to use a string also, so `"1"` instead of `1`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do this on a mac, but I used a class similar to this,

```
Option Explicit

Implements Scripting.Dictionary

Private dic As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Sub Add(Key As Variant, Item As Variant)
    dictionary_Add Key, Item
End Sub
Private Sub dictionary_Add(Key As Variant, Item As Variant)
    dic.Add Key, Item
End Sub
Public Sub Remove(Key As Variant)
    dictionary_Remove (Key)
End Sub
Private Sub dictionary_Remove(Key As Variant)
    dic.Remove (Key)
End Sub

Public Function TEST_LAMBDA(strLAMBDA As String) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim strSplit() As String
    Dim strCriteria As String

    Set TEST_LAMBDA = New Scripting.Dictionary

    strSplit = Split(strLAMBDA, "=>")
    strCriteria = strSplit(1)

    Dim intCounter As Integer
    strSplit = Split(strCriteria, "=")
    strCriteria = strSplit(1)

    For intCounter = 0 To dic.Count - 1
        If dic.Keys()(intCounter) = strCriteria Then
            TEST_LAMBDA.Add dic.Keys()(intCounter), dic.Items()(intCounter)
        End If
    Next intCounter

End Function
Private Property Get dictionary_CompareMode() As Scripting.CompareMethod
End Property
Private Property Let dictionary_CompareMode(ByVal RHS As Scripting.CompareMethod)
End Property
Private Property Get dictionary_Count() As Long
End Property
Private Function dictionary_Exists(Key As Variant) As Boolean
End Function
Private Property Get dictionary_HashVal(Key As Variant) As Variant
End Property
Private Property Get dictionary_Item(Key As Variant) As Variant
End Property
Private Property Let dictionary_Item(Key As Variant, RHS As Variant)
End Property
Private Property Set dictionary_Item(Key As Variant, RHS As Variant)
End Property
Private Function dictionary_Items() As Variant
End Function
Private Property Let dictionary_Key(Key As Variant, RHS As Variant)
End Property
Private Function dictionary_Keys() As Variant
End Function
Private Sub dictionary_RemoveAll()
End Sub
```

I used like so

```
Sub t()

Dim a As New clsDictionary

a.Add "9", "this out"
a.Add "10", "test"

Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary

Set d = a.TEST_LAMBDA("x=>x=9")

End Sub
```