# Microsoft Excel : Macros: VBA : Create Object Lisy

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to perform a Macro in Excel for MAC OS. When I am trying to set a list using below code, it gives me errors

```
Dim list
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

Please let me know if any issue for create object using ArrayList in mac. Error Screenshot below

[image: Error]

Comment: Hi. Mac OS cannot create ActiveX objects.. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151362/generic-list-of-structs-in-vba

Comment: You're trying to create an instance of a .NET class - those are not available on Mac.